# How many versions of a shirt can be made if it comes in $12$ colors, male or female fit, and $3$ sizes for each sex?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose there is a shirt of some brand. It comes in 12 colors, in Male or Female fit, and there are 3 sizes for both Male and Female. How many possible versions of the shirt can be made?

I've gotten as far as C(12,1) * C(2,1) but I am unsure as to how to translate the 3 sizes for Male and Female into a combination.

Comment: How about $12\cdot2\cdot3$???

Comment: This is a [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) problem.

Answer (score 3):

Each of the 3 categories: {color, male / female, size} are independent, so you just need to multiply the numbers of each category. Thus there are 12 x 2 x 3 = 72 possible versions.